# shifting array of strings C

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

I'm trying to create a function in C that shifts all of the elements (strings) up in an array and inserts a string at the end. For some reason though the function I've created causes all of the elements of the array to have the same value (the value that I'm inserting). I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

At first I thought that maybe its because they are strings and that the elements they are being moved to need to be reallocated in memory, but thought that I was just moving the memory locations of the strings anyway. I'm definitely misunderstanding something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
void addItem(char **list, char *item, int size){
    int i;

    // loop through the list and move everthing up
    for(i=0; i<size-1; i++){
        // move items up until we are at the last item
        list[i] = list[i+1];
    }
    // set the last item
    list[size-1] = item;
}
```

Comment: the arguments you pass to this function, how are they allocated? is size the size of the array or the number of elements in the array?

Comment: the list is being allocated at run time in the main function and then all of the elements are set to NULL. The string that is being added is taken from the users input.

Comment: Again, how is the string allocated? The problem is in the caller.

Comment: size is it the number of existing strings or the total size of your allocated array?

Comment: size is the total size of the array. The strings are scanned into a character pointer and then passed to the addItem function.

Comment: so if you have an array allocated for say 10 entries but user only has entered 4 entries then you will be assigning the new string to list[9] which is not correct.

Comment: well I waS trying to add them to the end of the array and shift everything else up. Is there a better way to do that. Should I reverse the function and add things to the top and push everything down?

Comment: you can just keep track of how many strings are in the list, then when you reach size you start shifting. so add another argument to your additem e.g. 'count'

Comment: @tiantang i added some code as an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I noticed that keeping track of how many strings had been input was not the actual solution to my problem. I had forgotten that I had changed part of the code prior to that and hadn't compiled it. I'm sorry for falsely marking the other answer.

The real solution to the problem is that the character pointer `char *item` is a variable scanned in in the main function. For some reason it did not hit me that `char *item` is a reference to the character array scanned in. That means `list[size-1] = item` is setting `list[size-1]` to the memory location of `char *item`. So basically over time `list` at any position is pointing to the same memory location. Thus the minute that `char *item` changes in the main function, it makes all of the elements of `list` equal to that value... A simple pointer mistake turned into a catastrophe.

This is the working code which utilizes `strcpy(), malloc() and free()` to appropriately solve this problem. The array `char **list`'s elements are all set to `NULL` in the main function to ensure we remove garbage.

```
void shiftInsert(char **list, char *item, int size){
     int i;

     // loop through the list and move everthing up
     for(i=(size-1); i>=0; i--){

        list[i] = list[i-1];
     }

     // clear our first item and allocate it
     free(list[0]);
     list[0] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(item));

     // set the last item
     strcpy(list[0], item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion how you can do it

```
void addItem(char **list, char* item, int* count, int size)
{
  int i = 0;
  if (*count == size)
  {  
    for (i = 0; i < size-1; ++i)
    {
      list[i] = list[i+1];
    }
    list[size-1] = item;
  }
  else
  {
    list[*count] = item;
    (*count)++;
  }
}
```

you need to differ between number of strings in the array and the max size of the array.

Comment: another way would be to keep order reversed shifting right and assign new element to 0th index.

Answer (score 0):

`addItem` is fine.

Well, it has an awful name for what it does.

Well, it relies on someone else freeing the pointer that used to be in `list[0]`, but it seems unlikely that this is happening, so you probably have a memory leak.

But it doesn't have an error that causes the problem you describe. The problem is elsewhere (i.e. in the caller).

I think you are repeatedly calling `addItem` with the same value (pointer) for `item`. As such, you end up with an array where every element is the same pointer.